# How to calculate average on single field using MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection in that collection field is **status**. Status is in arrayIndex format. Collection sample as follows
     [image]
I have to calculate the average 0, 1, and 2 after calculating i want result this format as shown follows

```
    {
  "result": [
    {
      "0": 18,
      "1": 58,
      "2": 24
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to make result in above format. If yes please suggest me how to calculate average?

Comment: Average of what? Of the status counts?

Comment: @chridam in status i want calculate average of NumberInt(0), NumberInt(1) and NumberInt(2)

Comment: So given the above two sample documents, what is your expected output?

Comment: @chridam i made changes in question so i want average of 0, 1, 2

Comment: @chridam again i made changes in question. when quey excute after that i want output Like in collection 0 are 18%, 1 are 58% and 2 are 24% or Average of 0 is 18, 1 is 58 and 2 is 24

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115516/discussion-between-dhanashri-and-chridam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mongodb shell query for running the aggregation operation to get the average of the first, second and third statuses in a given array follows:

```
var pipeline = [
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "Status.0": { $exists: true },
            "Status.1": { $exists: true },
            "Status.2": { $exists: true }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$Status" },
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "Status.0": { $exists: true },
            "Status.1": { $exists: true },
            "Status.2": { $exists: true }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "0": { "$avg": "$Status.0" },
            "1": { "$avg": "$Status.1" },
            "2": { "$avg": "$Status.2" }
        }
    }
]

db.status.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: you are genious... Thank you so much

Comment: @chirdam can i ask why are use $unwind?

Comment: We use the [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator since when it is applied on a list data field, it will generate a new record for each and every element of the list data field on which unwind is applied. It basically flattens the data so that you can process it as a single document in the preceding pipeline.